# Two-Dimention array keeps updating entire row instead of each cell, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm using python to illustrate DP algorithm. During memoization which keeps updating the table, I found that the table was not updated correctly.

I've narrowed down to the line "dp[t_id][_p] = max(choice_1, choice_2)", and I don't see what's the problem there.

```
tasks = [1,2,2,3]
dp = [[0]*(p+1)]*len(tasks)
for t_id in range(len(dp)):
    for _p in range(p+1):
        choice_1 = 1
        choice_2 = 2
        print dp
        dp[t_id][_p] = max(choice_1, choice_2)
        print dp
```

I expect the dp table should be updated one cell at a time, whereas `dp[0][0] = 2`, then `dp[0][1] = 2`, etc. However, it's updating as `dp[every_column][0] = 2`. The two prints in code should showcase the issue.

***screenshot***

[image]

Comment: How are you creating `dp`

Comment: @DanielMesejo ```dp = [[0]*(p+1)]*len(tasks)```

Comment: @ZDunker Please [edit] your question with all variable declarations so that we can run the code ourselves without any errors.

Comment: @ZDunker all dp[ i ] point to the same object if you create dp like that.

Comment: There has to be a gazillion dupes for that one.

Comment: @Muts Thank you so much for pointing this out. Is there a formal way to create a 2-D dp table?

Comment: Make a list comprehension with a dummy counter.

Answer (score 2):

```
dp = [[0]*(p+1)]*len(tasks)
```

This creates a list of references to the same list. Let's do a simpler example:

```
dp = [[0] * 5] * 5
dp[0][0] = 42
print(dp)
```

Output:

```
[[42, 0, 0, 0, 0], [42, 0, 0, 0, 0], [42, 0, 0, 0, 0], [42, 0, 0, 0, 0], [42, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

As you can see, it looks like the first element of each row is set to `42`. This is because each row is **the same list**. Instead, you need to create several independent lists with a list comprehension or a for loop. For example:

```
dp = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(6)]
dp[0][0] = 42
print(dp)
```

Output:

```
[[42, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now only the first element of the first row is set.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ZDunker It's an issue with Python it's easy for beginner to "by mistake" do a shallow copy. You can see the issue by using the `===` operator which check if two objects are actually the same object (and modifying one will therefore modify the other). `dp[0] === dp[1]` will return `True` with the first example, and `False` with the corrected one, because in the first the lines are all the same objects, while in the second they are all fresh new lines.

Comment: @Nonyme Python doesn't have a `===` operator. I think you mean the `is` operator.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you sir, both are good things to put on top of my head.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you are absolutely correct, sorry for that mistake.